# Liberty Profile exploded directory

Tags: websphere-liberty

So i'm trying to configure Maven Liberty Plugin to point to my war application in exploded format.

I'm able to do this for .war file but having issues with the constraint of having to have my project exploded in a directory named ../somewarfile.war/  this is an issue since my build also packages in this folder. I can't have both a .war file and .war directory in the same Maven Target Folder.

Is there a way to use exploded archive without having to name my folder somewarfile.war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the Liberty Maven Plug-in with a custom server.xml. That server.xml can have a *webApplication* element that points to the directory of the exploded war file.

For example, create your custom *server.xml* under *src/main/wlp* directory with:

```
...
<webApplication location="./target/myApp/" name="myApp"/>
...
```

Of course, the *location* attribute needs to be point to the right location.

And the Liberty Maven Plug-in is configured with:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <configFile>src/main/wlp/server.xml</configFile>
    ...
</configuration>
```